# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file maven

Tags: maven

I tried to execute the below command through command prompt:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=scertcommon-07.01.08.04.jar -DgroupId=com.avaya.sce -DartifactId=scertcommon -Dversion=07.01.08.04 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I am getting the following error when I executed the above command.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error installing artifact 'com.avaya.sce:scertcommon:jar?': Failed to install artifact com.avaya.sce:scertcommon:jar?:07.01.08.04: C:\Users\N0292812\.m2\repository\com\avaya\sce\scertcommon\07.01.08.04\scertcommon-07.01.08.04.jar? (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

One added point:
I do not use  pom.xml file and the  jar file is kept in D:/xx/xxx.So i navigated to the folder and executed the above command. 
What is the exact problem and how can I rectify the problem.I am quite new to Maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check why there is a '?' after artifact names in error message.

> ... Error installing artifact 'com.avaya.sce:scertcommon:jar? ...'

Maybe some invisible special character has slipped into your mvn command after artifact name.

I think that in Windows character '?' cannot be used in filenames/paths.

Comment: Thanks.Yes,it is an invisible special character which caused the problem